# Incorrect implemenation of BST deserialization in Python

Tags: python, binary-search-tree

This is my implementation of  BST in Python.

```
class BST:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None
        self.size = 0

    def insert(self, item):
        self.root = self.insert_helper(item, self.root)
        self.size += 1
        return self.root

    def insert_helper(self, item, root):
        if root is None:
            p = Node(item)
            root = p
            return root
        if item > root.data:
            root.right = self.insert_helper(item, root.right)
        else:
            root.left = self.insert_helper(item, root.left)
        return root


class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        if data is None:
            raise ValueError('Cannot create Node with None value.')
        self.data = data
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
```

Now I'm trying to `serialize` and `deserialize` the BST into a list and vice versa.

This is the serialization code.

```
def serialize(root):
    tree_list = []
    serialize_helper(root, tree_list)
    return tree_list


def serialize_helper(root, tree_list):
    if root is None:
        tree_list.append(sys.maxsize)
        return
    tree_list.append(root.data)
    serialize_helper(root.left, tree_list)
    serialize_helper(root.right, tree_list)
```

This works expectedly.This is the code for deserialization.

```
def deserialize(tree_list):
    index = 0
    return deserialize_helper(tree_list, index)


def deserialize_helper(tree_list, index):
    if index == len(tree_list) or tree_list[index] == sys.maxsize:
        return None
    root = Node(tree_list[index])
    index += 1
    root.left = deserialize_helper(tree_list, index)
    root.right = deserialize_helper(tree_list, index)
    return root
```

This code is buggy and duplicates a child node both on left and right. I've debugged the code and it seems that when the recursion folds out the index reduces and thus I'm getting this behavior. Can someone help me with this.

Comment: Unlike lists ints are immutable, therefore you can't change them in-place which means that you can't use them for side-effects. The easiest way out is for your helper to return the updated index. alongside the subtree. So you can reassign the new value to your one-level-up index.

Comment: @PaulPanzer I'm new to computer science, I vaguely understand what you're saying but would really appreciate if you explain the concepts of in-place and side effects a bit more.

Answer (score 3):

In Python there are two broad categories of objects immutable objects and mutable objects. It is essential to grasp how they differ:

```
a = [] # a list, lists are mutable
b = a  # b and a now reference the same object
b.append(1)  # change b and the change will be in-place
print(a)     # since a references the same object
# [1]

a = 1 # an int, ints are immutable
b = a # b and a may well reference the same object, but
b += 1   # since the object cannot change a new object is bound to b
print(a) # leaving a unaffected
# 1
```

Similarly, if you pass a list to a function and the function changes the list but doesn't explicitly return it, the changes will still be visible to the caller, in fact to anybody holding a reference to the list. Some people call this a side-effect. You are using this technique in your serialiser.

If you pass an immutable object like your `index` to a function and within the function operate on it the original object doesn't change. It's name in the function is just bound to new objects which are not visible to the caller, *unless* you explicitly return them.

So to fix your deserialiser try to return both the subtree and the current index like so,

```
return root, index
```

so the caller can update theirs like so

```
root.left, index = deserialize_helper(tree_list, index)
```

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't get Paul's answer to work readily, so here's how I finally managed to solve the problem. Thanks to Paul though for helping me understand the immutability and side effects issue, which was the primary bug. I used an iterator instead of an integer index.

```
def deserialize(tree_list):
    itr = iter(tree_list)
    return deserialize_helper(tree_list, itr)


def deserialize_helper(tree_list, itr):
    item = next(itr)
    if item is None or item == sys.maxsize:
        return None
    p = Node(item)
    p.left = deserialize_helper(tree_list, itr)
    p.right = deserialize_helper(tree_list, itr)
    return p
```

Comment: That's actually quite elegant!